# How can I import TLS certs for Idea's maven use in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, maven, powershell, intellij-idea

So I'm a little confused because there's like 3 versions of the jvm currently installed. It appears Idea15 ships with one that it uses,there's the auto updating JRE that's installed, then there's the development JDK.

My nexus server has an unsigned certificate that it uses. On linux I've just been importing as root, and fancily only one jvm. However I need to be able to install this cert on windows. This is more or less my translated command from linux.

`PS C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\keytool.exe' -importcert -keystore ..\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -file C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\r
pf\cert.pem
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on cmd in the menu, and do runas administrator, then use the keytool on the to modify the certs in the *jdk* version, not one of the other versions of the jvm.